# How to run with the composition of Spring + Hibernate + Cassandra

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, cassandra

I am currently looking for a Spring + Hibernate + Cassandra sample project.
Is not there anything good?

Although I tried looking and trying, I have tried various approaches, all of which failed.

What is interested as a way is by Hibernate OGM.

So I first made Spring + Hibernate + MySQL environment (it is working normally)
I decided to modify it.

Comment: Is this on your classpath org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.cassandra.CassandraCQL2Dialect? Are you missing a JAR?

Comment: Gumenimeda, Thank you for your comment.
My project's pom.xml has the following settings.

https://github.com/hidetarou2013/SpringDataBaseSample/blob/feature/cassandra_1/pom.xml


In hibernate-ogm-cassandra-4.2.0.Final.jar,

org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.cassandra.CassandraDialect
There is,

org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.cassandra.CandandraCQL 2 Dialect
There was not.


By the way, there was no CassandraCQL2Dialect in hibernate-ogm-core-4.2.0.Final
We believe that dependency setting is not enough ...

But what is it ?....

Comment: I refer to the following information, but I have no information on "hibernate.dialect".
By the way, hibernate-ogm-cassandra is set by artifactId.

[LINK](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/4.2/reference/en-US/html/ch14.html#cassandra_specific_configuration_properties)

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=org.hibernate.ogm

org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.cassandra.CassandraCQL2Dialect　　Where on earth is it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally not use any hibernate related tooling for Cassandra. Have you looked at [Spring Data for Cassandra](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-cassandra/) instead?

What you need to know with these tools is that object-relationship-mapping (ORM) is far less useful to have compared to using a relational database. Data in Cassandra should be stored using a *denormalized* data model, which implies that your queries should be able to retrieve all relevant data from a single table if possible.

Being able to create queries programmatically will probably also bring no advantages. Tables in Cassandra can only be optimized for a limited number of queries and in most cases you'll only use 1-2 queries to retrieve data based on the combination of keys.

Although some basic POJO mapping can be convenient, ORM frameworks play a far less significant role for Cassandra compared to traditional RDMS applications.

Comment: To Stefan Podkowinski

I am sorry for the delay in response. Thank you for your valuable advice.

Spring Data for Cassandra
I also want to investigate.

However, in my experience with Spring MVC, I made Entity and DAO,
I am used to using org.hibernate.Session or org.hibernate.Query, and I want to use Transaction there for anything.

In Spring Data for Cassandra, I would like to see if there are easy-to-understand samples.

Answer (score 0):

There are some configuration properties that are not needed for OGM:

- Hibernate OGM does not need this property: hibernate.ogm.cassandra.url
- You should set "hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" to CASSANDRA_EXPERIMENTAL
- Hibernate OGM does not need the property "hibernate.dialect"

Comment: I did not know that. Thank you for telling me valuable information. I will check it later.